# Reorganise columns based on row 2 values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sort columns alphabetically based on the values of cells in Row 2.

Can't figure out what's wrong here - it seems to work only for the first column and then it stops.

```
Sub reorganise()
Dim v As Variant, x As Variant, findfield As Variant
Dim oCell As Range
Dim iNum As Long
Dim wsa As Worksheet

Set wsa = Worksheets("Skills")

v = Array(wsa.Range("B2", wsa.Cells(2, wsa.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)))

For x = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
findfield = v(x)
iNum = iNum + 1
Set oCell = wsa.Rows(2).Find(What:=findfield, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not oCell.Column = iNum Then
Columns(oCell.Column).Cut
Columns(iNum).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
End If
Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: I think the problem lies in the array. Because i am assigning a range to the array, LBound and UBound lead to errors (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have figured it out.. was a bit more complicated but here is the full code:

```
Sub reorganise()
Dim v
Dim x
Dim findfield As Variant
Dim oCell As Range
Dim iNum As Long
Dim wsa As Worksheet
Dim inputArray() As Variant

Set wsa = Worksheets("Skills")

With wsa
Set v = .Range("A2", .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
End With

v = Application.Transpose(v)

Call BubbleSort(v)

For x = LBound(v, 1) To UBound(v, 1)
findfield = v(x, 1)
iNum = iNum + 1
Set oCell = wsa.Rows(2).Find(What:=findfield, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not oCell.Column = iNum Then
Columns(oCell.Column).Cut
Columns(iNum).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
End If
Next x
End Sub

Sub BubbleSort(arr)
  Dim strTemp As String
  Dim i As Long
  Dim j As Long
  Dim lngMin As Long
  Dim lngMax As Long
  lngMin = LBound(arr, 1)
  lngMax = UBound(arr, 1)
  For i = lngMin To lngMax - 1
    For j = i + 1 To lngMax
      If arr(i, 1) > arr(j, 1) Then
        strTemp = arr(i, 1)
        arr(i, 1) = arr(j, 1)
        arr(j, 1) = strTemp
      End If
    Next j
  Next i
End Sub
```

Basically in addition to what you said, I had to:

- Transpose the array
- Change the `LBound` and `Ubound` and `findfield` syntax
- Come up with an additional procedure to sort out the values of the array alphabetically

Answer (score 0):

1) assign directly the range to your variant variable v - without the Array function. When using the array function, what you are doing is assign an array of one element - consisting of your range returned as an array - to your variable v

2) v will contain a 2 dimensions array:

- first dimension will be 1 - for one row returned
- second dimension will be as many columns as returned by the range

Then loop through the second dimension of this array - I haven't checked the rest of the code but this should get you on your way

Comment: thanks this leads to an error (mismatch) though at: 'For x = LBound(v) To UBound(v)'

Comment: i tried: For x = LBound(v, 2) To UBound(v, 2)  and still get error, although i checked the array has 2 dimensions as you describe..

Comment: figured it out, see my answer !